# Swift: Working with elements from UIKit in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uikit

I started creating a simple game in Swift and I did not use the Single View templet (UIKit) but the Game templet (SpriteKit).

I am missing a few elements in the Game templet like the UITextfield for example and I wanted to know, if there are better ways to implement the Textfield via SpriteKit without importing UIKit because I read that this is bad coding and should not be done.

Comment: Is there a question somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't you use `UIKit` and `UITextField`? It´s the default element and what´s preferred to used. If you don´t want to use `UIKit` then you should look at some 3rd party element, but I can recommend the default elements.

Comment: okay, I read that it is bad coding to switch between UIKit and SpriteKit, but maybe that was rubbish.

Comment: Where did you read that? Both are developed and native elements by Apple, so use it and you´ll be fine. I always prefer the built in elements.

Comment: SpriteKit and UIKit do not exactly play well together.  For instance, you can not put a UITextField into an SKScene, you would have to attach it to the SKView making the UITextField always appear above any of the scene elements.